# Pedir 2 datos y guardar valores en un array

Tags: java, array

El ejercicio me pide 2 datos (dorsal y categoria) de varios participantes (máximo 10) que guardo en dos arrays. Cuando quiero que me devuelva los resultados, solo me muestra el del último participante, los demás no se guardan o toman otro valor. A ver si alguien puede ayudarme!

```
import java.util.Scanner;    
public static void main(String[] args) {
Scanner lector = new Scanner(System.in);

    int intentos=0,i=0, respuestaDatos, contadorParticipantes=0;
    boolean introducirDatos=true;
    String nombreCategoria="";   
    int [] dorsal = new int [10];
    int [] categoria = new int [10];
    
do{
System.out.print("Introduce el dorsal:");
        dorsal[i]=lector.nextInt();
    
System.out.print("Introduce la categoria: infantil (0), junior (1), senior(2):");
        categoria[i]=lector.nextInt();
        intentos++;
        switch (categoria[i]){
            case 0:
                nombreCategoria="infantil";
                break;
            case 1:
                nombreCategoria="junior";
                break;
            case 2:
                nombreCategoria="senior";
                break;
                }   

System.out.print("Quieres introducir más datos (0:no 1:si)?");
respuestaDatos=lector.nextInt();
    if (respuestaDatos==0){
        introducirDatos=false;
    }
    if (respuestaDatos==1){
        introducirDatos=true;
    }  
contadorParticipantes++;
}while(introducirDatos);
    for (int j=0;j<contadorParticipantes;j++){
    System.out.print("Dorsal: "+dorsal[j]+" Categoria: "+nombreCategoria+"\n");
    }    
}
}
```

Comment: ¿donde incrementas la variable i? Todos los casos lo vas guardar en el indice 0 por lo que se sobreescriben los valores en cada iteración

Answer (score 2):

Creo que en ningún momento incrementas la i, por lo que todo el rato se almacenan en la posición 0 y se superponen. Junto a contadorparticipantes++ prueba a poner i++